# Oracle select for update behavior in query with IN clause

Tags: oracle, locking

Given the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE user_id in (10,20,30,40,50) FOR UPDATE
```

How is Oracle going to lock all these rows? Is it going to lock them one by one (during index scan) OR Oracle somehow will lock all of them at the same time?

What if second transaction simultaneously runs the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE user_id = 50 FOR UPDATE
```

It is possible that second transaction WILL BE able to acquire a lock for this record just because the first transaction hasn't acquired a lock for this concrete record yet (due to sequential row one by one locking ) ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: since Oracle (like other rdbms) always uses read consistency on statement level the consistent resultset is defined before the actual locking takes place (and so the operation is ACID based). Though I am sure that this is true, I did not find a supporting piece of documentation.